# Object hierarchies in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, design-patterns, inheritance

I've been introduced to an Objective-C codebase which has ~50,000 LoC and I'd estimate that 25% or so is duplicate code. Unfortunately, OO principles have been mostly ignored up to this point in the codebase in favor of copy and pasting logic. Yay!

I'm coming from a Java background and a lot of this duplication is fixable with good old-fashioned objective oriented programming. Extracting shared logic into a base class feels like the correct solution in a lot of cases.

However, before I embark on creating a bunch of base classes and sharing common logic between derived classes, I thought I should stop and see if there are any other options available to me. After watching Ken Kocienda's 'Writing Easy-To-Change Code' WWDC session from 2011, he's advising me to keep object hierarchies as shallow as possible. He doesn't offer up any hard statistics as to why he has this opinion, so I'm wondering whether I'm missing out on something.

I'm not an Objective-C expert by any stretch of the imagination, so I'm wondering if there's any best practices when deciding on an object hierarchy. Basically, I'd like to get opinions on when you decide to stop creating base classes and start using composition instead of inheritance as a way of sharing code between classes.

Also, from a runtime performance standpoint, is there anything to sway me away from creating  object hierarchies?

Comment: Having hierarchies as flat as possible and favoring composition over inheritance is good practice in any object oriented language, but, like in Java, the language doesn't stop you from creating sky-high hierarchies if that's what you want to do. As opposed to Java though, Objective-C adds the concept of categories, which should help flatten hierarchies. There's also the class cluster pattern that helps keeping private classes private and only exposing a certain public interface, in a way which is rather different than what Java provides.

Comment: I would say that you should make sure you're aware of `id`, `@protocol` and protocol conformance before you begin. I believe this all maps to Java, though I don't remember what they're called in Java. You'll probably still create a mess, but hopefully a lesser mess than you have now. Also, look at using doxygen with options to include all sources to make the code more browsable. (Usually, I'd suggest appledoc for documentation, but code browsing is a different need.)

Comment: Radu - looking at the codebase, I think I could manage to get rid of 90% of duplicate code with 2 or 3 levels of inheritance which I don't believe constitutes cognitive overload for developers on the project. I've been using categories a little - they seem like little static helper functions for the most part. The seem best suited to extending classes provided in the SDK like NSString

Comment: `@protocol` is similar to `interface` in Java, and `id` is pretty much `Object`. `id <protocol>` is similar to an object implementing the specified protocol (interface) in Java.

Comment: Tests, tests, tests and then some more tests - if you think you can remove 90% of a code base then I hope your testing to make sure you aren't breaking it as you go

Comment: I'm aware of @protocol and id. They're very handy for codifying contracts & generalizing return values or parameters to methods. Is anyone aware of a runtime impact on performance in Objective-C due to deep hierarchies?

Comment: Hey Paul.s - Testing is something that I'm definitely looking into to ensure I don't break the app during any potential refactoring. I'm looking to execute this on a piecemeal basis as opposed to one big massive change to the entire codebase to reduce the overall risk.

Comment: @seanoshea, if you're looking at a large refactoring job, I recommend you take a look at [AppCode](http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/), which is hugely better at refactoring than Xcode. As for performance impact due to deep hierarchies, it basically shouldn't be any different than in Java for example. The difference though is that Java uses static binding, so it has more options for optimization than Objective-C, which uses message passing, and therefore is always doing late binding.

Comment: Thanks for the AppCode recommendation Radu. I'll definitely take a look at that. It feels like arguing that deep hierarchies in Objective-C is a poor idea from a performance perspective is entering hair-splitting territory (especially if I can keep it to 2 - 3 levels). I'll investigate late binding though just from an educational standpoint. Cheers.

Comment: @seanoshea, the fact that Objective-C is late binding really shouldn't affect the way you use the language, this is an implementation detail. The only time I had a problem with this was in a performance critical area of the code, where switching to a macro instead of sending a message a few thousands of times per second provided an extreme increase in performance (`objc_msgSend()` does add some overhead, even though not significant, but you can definitely see it in performance critical situations).

Comment: Yeah - that's the way I was approaching this. Interesting stuff all the same - thanks for the back-history.

Comment: Deep hierarchies only affect performance for alloc/dealloc, where multiple layers of methods must be traversed.  Otherwise, call efficiency is not affected by the depth of hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote up some thoughts awhile back on [coming to iOS from other backgrounds](http://robnapier.net/blog/learning-cocoa-2-467), including Java. Some things have changed due to ARC. In particular, memory management is no longer so front-and-center. That said, all the things you used to do to make memory management easy (use accessors, use accessors, use accessors) is still equally valid in ARC.

@Radu is completely correct that you should often keep your class hierarchies fairly simple and shallow (as you read). Composition is often a much better approach in Cocoa than extensive subclassing (this is likely true in Java, too, but it's common practice in ObjC). ObjC also has no concept of an abstract method or class, which makes certain kinds of subclassing a little awkward. Rather than extracting shared logic into base classes (particularly abstract base classes), it is often better to extract them into a separate strategy object.

Look at `UITableView` and its use of delegates and datasources. Look at things like `NSAttributedString` which HAS-A `NSString` rather than IS-A. That's common and often keeps things cleaner. As with all large object hierarchies, keep [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) in mind at all times. I see a lot of ObjC design go sideways when someone forgets that [a square is not a rectangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem). Again, this is true of all languages, but it's worth remembering as you design.

Immutable (value) objects are a real win whenever you can use them.

The other piece you will quickly discover is that there are very few "safety decorations" like "final" or "protected" (there is a `@protected`, but it isn't actually that useful in practice and is seldom used). People from a Java and C++ background tend to fret about compiler enforcement of various access rules. ObjC doesn't have compiler enforcement of most protections (you can always send any message you want to any object at runtime). You just use consistent naming conventions and don't go poking around at private methods. Programmer discipline takes the place of compiler enforcement. In practice, it works just fine that way in the vast majority of cases.

That said, ObjC has a lot of warnings, and you absolutely must eliminate all warnings. Most ObjC warnings are actually errors.

I've strayed a little from the specific question of object hierarchies, but hopefully it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

One major problem with deep hierarchies in Objective-C is that Xcode doesn't help you at all understanding/managing them.  Another is simply that just about anything in Objective-C gets about twice as complex than the equivalent in Java, so you need to work harder to keep stuff simple.

But I find composition in Objective-C to be awkward (though I can't say exactly why), so there is no "perfect" answer.

I have observed that small subroutines are much rarer in Objective-C vs Java, and one is much more likely to see code duplicated between mostly-identical view controllers and the like.  I think a big part of this is simply the development tools and the relative awkwardness with creating new classes.

PS:  I had to rework an app that contained roughly 55K lines, close as we could count.  As you found, there was likely about 25% duplication, but there was also another 25% or so of totally dead code.  (Thankfully, that app has been pretty much abandoned since.)

Comment: "Another is simply that just about anything in Objective-C gets about twice as complex than the equivalent in Java, so you need to work harder to keep stuff simple." This is a very strange comment. Almost every conversation I have with Java teams includes a lot of "well, we can't do X so easily in Java" (which lines up pretty closely with my experience developing in it). I've never had trouble creating new classes. I only have trouble if you have complex inheritance (but Cocoa design discourages that; the language matches the design choice that favors composition).

Comment: I'm definitely not saying that ObjC couldn't use some improvements in inheritance (a language construct for protected methods would often be useful, and there are several little "gotchas" around categories that could definitely be improved on. My experience with Android teams suggested that it was easier there to go completely custom or 100% stock (doing exactly what the API developers had in mind), but if you wanted to be a little custom, Cocoa seems much simpler and flexible due to its heavy use of delegation. Just my experience there; I haven't written a lot of Android code.

Comment: @RobNapier -- I was talking about the languages, not the UI platforms.  And Android is a horrible design, quite unrelated to the choice of Java as the primary language.